# How can I remove the new stats message?

Tags: wp-admin, plugin-jetpack

I've recently (latest update) been welcomed to my stats page with this annoying message:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to remove that offensive red "did you know" message?

**Edit:**

Looks like adding:

```
.gotonewdash {display: none;}
```

to wp-admin/css/wp-admin.min.css did the trick of hiding it, but according To Tom J Nowell, this is a big no-no. Does anyone have recommendation for doing this properly?

Answer (score 4):

The next level up would be an inline style in the head using a hook in a dedicated plugin or theme functions.php:

```
function add_admin_css(){
    ?><style>.gotonewdash {display: none;}</style><?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head','add_admin_css');
```

Next level up after that would be an admin.css in a plugin with `is_admin()` and `wp_enqueue_style`